# get request to accepts params in postman, currently sends a unsupported media type error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, postman, get-request

I've built different get methods using body request to select an id (with raw json). However, as I learned that get methods doesn't support body request, I would like to change so that I can use params in postman insted. However, when I do it now, I get an 415 Unsupported Media Type.

Here's the method:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<RentReason>> getRentReason(RentReason model)
    {  
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("@rentId", model.rentreasonId);
        var getAllRentReason = await _sqlconnection.QueryAsync<RentReason>($@"SELECT 
        CostItem.ID as rentreasonId,
        CostItem.CostItemTypeID as claimReason,
        RequestRentServiceReason.Name as rentReason, 
        RequestRentServiceCartype.Name as RentServiceCarTypeID, 
        DateFrom, DateTo, Price as totalPrice 
        FROM CostItem 
        INNER JOIN RequestRentServiceReason ON CostItem.RentReasonID = RequestRentServiceReason.ID
        INNER JOIN RequestRentServiceCartype ON CostItem.RentServiceCartypeID = RequestRentServiceCartype.ID
        WHERE CostItem.ID = @rentId", parameters);
        return getAllRentReason;
    }
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> getRentReason(RentReason model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            try
            {
                var list = await _request.getRentReason(model);
                return Ok(list);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
            return Ok();
        }
```

Interface class:

```
Task<IEnumerable<RentReason>> getRentReason(RentReason model);
```

Before I sent requests in the body like:

```
{
    "rentreasonId": "40"
}
```

But I would like to send it in the params insted so for example:

```
https://localhost/Request/getRentReason?rentreasonId=40
```

Anyone know how to achive this?

Comment: `public async Task<IActionResult> getRentReason([FromQuery] RentReason rentreasonId)` ?

Comment: @Fildor it works, I just had to change the controller and the method. Thank you so much! If you answer the question I  can accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have method parameters bound to query parameters by using the [`[FromQuery]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromqueryattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0) Attribute.

In your case, it should look something like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> getRentReason([FromQuery] int rentreasonId)
```

which will enable you to use `<your controller path>/rentReason?rentreasonId=40`

---

However, I'd recommend to use route parameters for this:

```
[HttpGet("/your/api/route/rentreason/{rentreasonId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> getRentReason([FromRoute] int rentreasonId)
```

Which will get you something like `<authority>/your/api/route/rentreason/40`.

For reference: [FromRouteAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromrouteattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0)